# How to use switch case in onDateSet

Tags: android

I am going to use multiple date pickers how can i use switch case in OnDateSet.

labelSelectedDate = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.textview_label_selected_date);//From date

```
        labelSelectedDateTo= (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.textview_label_selected_date_todate); //To date

        selectedDate = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.textview_selected_date);  //From date

        selectedDateTo= (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.textview_selected_date_todate); //To date

        datePicker = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.imageview_date_picker); //From date

        datePickerTo= (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.imageview_date_picker_todate);//To date
```

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    Date date = calendar.getTime();

    switch () {

        case :

            selectedDateForSalesVsTarget = CashPunditUtils.formatDate(date, "MM-dd-yyyy");

            Log.d(TAG, "Date Set : " + selectedDateForSalesVsTarget);

            if (selectedDate != null) {

                selectedDate.setText(CashPunditUtils.formatDate(date, "dd MMM yy"));

            }
            CashPunditUtils.viewId++;
            break;
        case :

            selectedDateForSalesVsTargetTo = CashPunditUtils.formatDate(date, "MM-dd-yyyy");

            Log.d(TAG, "Date Set : " + selectedDateForSalesVsTarget);

            if (selectedDateTo != null) {

                selectedDateTo.setText(CashPunditUtils.formatDate(date, "dd MMM yy"));
            }

            break;
    }
    loadSummaryReports(SALES_VS_TARGET_REPORT, false);
}
```

Comment: Do you even know how switch case works in any programming language?

Comment: ya i know, why i left the blank in switch because i don't no what i have to do there.

Comment: I created another class for that.

Comment: <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pick_date"
    android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog" />
When the user clicks this button, the system calls the following method:

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();

Comment: public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // use the current date as default date in the date picker
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

Comment: if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        // Create a new instance of date picker dialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), android.support.v7.appcompat.R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog, onDateSetListener, year, month, day);

        else
            return new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), onDateSetListener, year, month, day);
    }

    public void setOnDateSetListener(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener onDateSetListener){

        this.onDateSetListener = onDateSetListener;
    }
}

Comment: please check i pasted code step by step.

Answer (score 0):

pass view.getId() in switch and use different R.id.datapickerid in different cases

Comment: switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.imageview_date_picker: {   code   } and                      case R.id.imageview_date_picker_todate : {  code  } i tried but not executing.